# Criar instância da classe dinamicamente PHP com Namespace

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

```
$class = ucfirst(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . "Controller";    
include $class . ".php";    
$item = new $class();
```

---

Porém se coloco nome da classe sem ser dinamicamente, por exemplo:

```
$item = new PessoaController();
```

Está aceitando normalmente. Gostaria de saber como resolver e porque dinamicamente ele diz que a classe não existe?

Comment: Certeza que o caminho está correto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tem uma classe dentro de um namespace o mesmo deve ser declarado junto!!!

*Exemplo:*

```
<?php namespace Controller {
        
       class CarroController {
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo "PHP";
        }
       }
    }
```

*Solução*

```
<?php 
    
    $class = ucfirst(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . "Controller";    
    include $class . ".php";    
    $namespaceClass = "\\Controller\\".$class;
    $item = new $namespaceClass;
```

ou (com [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php))

```
<?php 
    
    $class = ucfirst(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . "Controller";    
    include $class . ".php";    
    $namespaceClass = "\\Controller\\".$class;
    $item = new ReflectionClass($namespaceClass);
    $ins = $item->newInstance();
```

*Resultado*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Porque do Erro?

Se você utilizar `$item = new $class` ele não está passando o namespace e consequentemente da um erro assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Declarações de namespace em [php](/questions/tagged/php)

***Definindo um namespace em um arquivo***

[*Referência*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)

```
<?php namespace Exemplo1;
        class Connection { /* code */ }
        function Open() { /* code */  }
```

***Definindo múltiplos namespace em arquivo***

*[Referência](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)*

```
<?php
    namespace Exemplo1 {
        class Connection { /* code */ }
        function Open() { /* code */  }
    }
    
    namespace Exemplo2 {
        const Value = 1;
        class Db { /* code */ }
        function Close() { /* code */  }
    }
    namespace { // código global
            session_start();
            function DateTime(){ /* code */ }    
    }
```

***Definindo namespace com hierarquia***

[*Referência*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php)

```
<?php namespace Code\Connection\Db;
        class Connection { /* code */ }
        function Open() { /* code */  }
```

Comment: FCCDias, só um detalhe: a declaração do namespace no seu exemplo estava incorreta. Editei sua resposta

Comment: @gmsantos você editou e eu reeditei porque existe as duas formas

Comment: Vlw unica coisa que estava faltando era colocar o namespace do objeto a ser instaciado na hora de utilizar ele, não entendi o porque de usar isso quando ele é uma dinamica e não precisa disso quando for feito de forma ingessada.

Comment: @FCCDias, não conhecia a segunda forma. Vale a pena citar que na segunda forma, tudo o que estiver fora do `namespace { }` no mesmo arquivo irá resultar em um erro.

Comment: @gmsantos já foram postado as maneiras de criação

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe está correta. Verifique se o caminho do include está correto caso esteja e mesmo assim não funcione adicione a função trim() em seu parse.

```
$class = trim(ucfirst(strtolower($_GET['type']))) . "Controller";    
include $class . ".php";    
$item = new $class();
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar por favor poste o erro aqui.