# Instanciar objetos dinamicamente

Tags: php, reflexão

Quando crio um novo objeto dentro do laço de repetição, que tem o nome em `$sizeName`, e tento acessar o método `getUrl()` obtenho:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUrl() on a non-object in ...
>   on line 58

```
foreach ($this->sizeNames as $sizeName => $sizeAlias)
    foreach ($sizeAlias as $alias)
        if ($size === $alias)
            $thumb = new $sizeName($image[0], $sizeAlias);

    return array(URL . $thumb->getUrl(), $image[1], $image[2], $image[3]);
```

Este é o método:

```
private static $url;
private static $width;
private static $height;

protected function getUrl()
{
    return self::$url . '/' . self::$width . '/' . self::$height;
}
```

O código entra nos laços de repetição e na condição.

```
var_dump($thumb); //retorna object(....
```

Quando instancio o objeto fora do laço de repetição o código funciona como o esperado.
Estou usando os modificadores de acesso de forma equivocada?

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14347/criar-inst%C3%A2ncia-da-classe-dinamicamente-php-com-namespace) mas não ajudou.

Comment: Seu objeto `$thumb` é apenas criado se entrar no if se não entrar da o erro que está na pergunta.

Comment: O mais interessante é que isso não acontece no PHP 7.

Comment: Seu método é protected, precisaria ser public, não?

Comment: Presumo que não @bfavaretto. `$sizeName` é uma classe que extende a que possui o método. O @rray tem razão, como o trecho de código é executado centenas de vezes não percebi que em alguns casos não entrava no `if`.

Comment: Na verdade eu tinha que ser `public` mesmo, hein? Protected só seria acessível de dentro da classe (ou derivadas).

Comment: Exatamente @bfavaretto, `$thumb` é derivado da classe que tem o método `getUrl()`.

Comment: Davi, mas você está chamando de fora da própria classe (a partir de uma instância). Nesse caso, precisa ser public. Não é, @rray? Independentemente de entrar ou não no if.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45355/discussion-between-daviaragao-and-bfavaretto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro acontece porque a condição do `if` não é atendida em todos os casos e por isso `$thumb` nem sempre tem um objeto e o método `getUrl()` não existe. Para resolver o problema basta garantir que `$thumb` tem um objeto antes de acessar ao método:

```
foreach ($this->sizeNames as $sizeName => $sizeAlias)
    foreach ($sizeAlias as $alias)
        if ($size === $alias)
            $thumb = new $sizeName($image[0], $sizeAlias);

return (is_object($thumb)) ? array(URL . $thumb->getUrl(), $image[1], $image[2], $image[3]) : $image;
```